# char pointer corrupted after passing as parameter

Tags: c, string, memory

I have a function like this

```
#define LEN 10
#define MAX 200
void f(char test[][LEN])
```

I have a code like this

```
char test[MAX][LEN];
:
:
f(test);
```

Now when I trace the code using dbx.

Immediately Before the calling of the function f, I print the variable, the array are all empty. And then afher the function f(test) is called, the pointer is corrupted and some element of the array is pointing to crap memory. It happens just after the parameter is passed.

What might be the reason?

I am working on this for a long time and totally lost.

Could anybody offer a hint?

Comment: Can you show us the code before `f(test)` and the body of the `f` function?

Comment: I think you'll need to post at least some of the code for `f()`.

Comment: but the problem is I print the variable immediately before the calling of the funcation and after the parameter is passed. The body of the function is not excuted yet.

Comment: There are no pointers in the definition of `test` , and i't passed by value. However, a buffer overflow in `f()` could change the value of `test` in `main` .

Comment: I thought you said you called the function? Please show us the code in its entirety. Are you actually populating your 2D array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly corrupting the stack.

It could be some function which is called before `f` and needs to return a value and not all execution paths end in a `return` statement.